# how to slice a pandas data frame with for loop in another list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, for-loop

I have a dataframe like this but Its **not necessary that there are just 3 sites** always:

```
data = [[501620, 501441,501549], [501832, 501441,501549], [528595, 501662,501549],[501905,501441,501956],[501913,501441,501549]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["site_0", "site_1","site_2"])
```

I want to slice the dataframe which can take condition dynemically from li(list) element and random combination.
I have tried below code which is a static one:

```
li = [1,2]
random_com = (501620, 501441,501549)
df_ = df[(df["site_"+str(li[0])] == random_com[li[0]]) & \
            (df["site_"+str(li[1])] == random_com[li[1]])]
```

How can I make the above code dynemic ?

I have tried this but It is giving me two different dataframe but I need one dataframe with both condition (AND).

```
 [df[(df["site_"+str(j)] == random_com[j])] for j in li]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do an iteration over the conditions and create an `&` of all the conditions.

```
li = [1,2]
main_mask = True
for i in li:
    main_mask = main_mask & (df["site_"+str(i)] == random_com[i])
df_ = df[main_mask]
```

Comment: I have a question if I have multiple sites than, I mean not necessary it will be just three every time ?

Comment: You can add any number of conditions. You might need to use another for loop and add conditions as `df["site_"+str(j) == <something>]`

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer one-liner, I think you could use [reduce()](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functools.html#functools.reduce)

```py
df_ = df[reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, [(df["site_"+str(j)] == random_com[j]) for j in li])]
```

Comment: It's giving me keyError 1

Comment: @NiraliKhoda By using `df[j]` in your code, what do want to retrieve?

Comment: I need the sliced dataframe @Ynjxsjmh

Comment: @NiraliKhoda Slice what? Column or row?

Comment: @NiraliKhoda Honestly speaking, I just translate `[df[(df["site_"+str(j)] == df[j])] for j in li]` in your post to `reduce()` version. I didn't test it and don't know what you want. If the original works, this should work too.

Comment: I wanted to slice rows. Even if columns are any number(1-10) or any number.